# Bricked BeagleBone Blue -- now what?

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

My BBBlue appears to be bricked.  Everything was fine, then I pressed the power button a few seconds, it shut down, and after that it won't power up.  Two <s>blue</s> Green LEDs come on with battery connect or 12 V power, but no blink, no battery state, etc.  I've tried various combinations of battery, USB, and 12 V power, but I only get the 75% Battery LED, and the Green user LED.  When I press the reset button, those LEDs go dim, but not off entirely.

3.3 V and 5.0 V rails are working.

Both Red User LED and 25% Battery LED have a short pulse about once per second.

I put the Red User LED on an oscope and this is what I see:
[image]

Red User LED again, with zoom:
[image]

And on the 25% LED...
[image]

The 25% LED does the above waveform interspersed with a boring 10 us pulse every second or so.

When I plug it into USB on Windows, the COM port shows up in Device Manager, but when I try opening up that port in Putty, it says it can't connect.  Anyway, even when it did boot, it took a while for the the COM port to be connectable, so I expect there is some software that needs to run for it to work (there is no FTDI chip + USB hub on the board).  That said, I'm not sure how a COM port can appear on USB without the SoC booting up, unless that's built into the SoC host capability hardware somehow.

The "removable drive" that normally appears doesn't show up.

I tried putting in the SD card which I had previously used to flash the eMMC to the latest image, but no response there (I was expecting the LEDs to flash while the script copied the contents of the SD card to the eMMC).

What's next?  Is there a hard serial port on the board, not USB, so I can try to observe that?  None of the connector pins had a UART or any other waveform on them whatsoever -- just either 3.3, GND, or some version of an almost-alive pulse as in the waveforms.

Pressing any of the buttons, then power-cycle and release, with SD card in place, does not change anything.

It appears something is trying to boot up, but it can't.
Is the PMIC in the SoC dead?
Or should I realize my time is valuable and just buy another one?

thanks

Comment: Normally, Beaglebones do have a console on UART0, you can try that. Apparently Beaglebone blue is poorly documented and have no SRM, so you can only guess and try...

Comment: There's a wiki with *some* content: https://github.com/beagleboard/beaglebone-blue/wiki/Pinouts

Comment: Have you tried powering up with the SD-card inserted and the *boot select* button held pressed?

Comment: Thanks, there is no "Boot select" label as such.  I see power, reset, mode, and pause buttons.  Power cycling with these held down, then released, with SD card in place didn't do anything.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beagleboard/beaglebone-blue/master/docs/BeagleBone_Blue_balloons.png has the button pointed out. Have you managed to read the UART0 output yet?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the boot button.  I pressed it while powering on and having SD card installed, and it sat there for a while seemingly doing nothing, then the lights came up and the user LEDs were doing a sequential pattern.  During this time there was no COM port or virt. enet port in Windows; ditto after power cycle w/o SD card. I did the boot select button again, and after ~15 minutes the LEDs stopped.  Power cycle again, and Windows does the USB sound but nothing shows up, and the green and red user LEDs are on but dim.  I ordered some JST cables for UART viewing on the scope again.

Comment: I finally got the SH connector for UART0, and I got a new BBBlue for reference, and i can finally see some output when the card is flashing and the LEDs are doing the knight rider thing.  I'll post the details on the BB discussion forum.

Comment: I flashed it again and this time it seemed to "take".  Not sure why.  Maybe it knew I was spying on it via the UART0.  So my board is working again.  Yay.